# How to perform Nunit testing for a class inherting from a base class with parameterised constructor

Tags: c#, nunit

```
namespace TestBI
{
 [TestFixture]
 class ClassChild:ClassParent
 {
    public ClassChild(DataRow row, string name): base(row, detail) { }
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        DataRow dr = new DataRow();
        dr[0] = 1;
        dr[1] = "ram"  
        ClassChild ch = new ClassChild(dr,"student");

        :
        :
        :
        Assert.AreEqual(string1,string2);
     }

 }
}
```

When I run the test,i get an error as "TestBI.ChildClass.Test suitable constructor was found"

How do i need to pass parameters here to child class?

Comment: Well what does `ClassParent` look like? What version of NUnit? How are you running it? Direct with the NUnit GUI? NUnit Command line? A third party unit test runner? (Like Resharper?)

Comment: ClassParent Contains Actual test Method which returns me a string.

Comment: Post the code of that class.

Comment: What is the reason to create Fixture instance within Test method?

Answer (score 1):

Provide a zero argument constructor for your test class.
It is fine if it calls a multiple argument constructor of the superclass, as long as it provides it with proper arguments.

Comment: This is also the case with F# test classes. E.g., `[<TestFixture>] type MyTests()`, not `[<TestFixture>] type MyTests`