# How to perform NUnit testing in a project on class level?

Tags: c#, nunit

I want to perform an NUnit Testing on a method of my project. Here **SerializeBinary()** method is converting object into binary streams and 
**DeserializeFromBinaryStream()** method once again convert it into previous same object format.now I want to check wheather these both objects are same or not after DesirializingFromBinary() method task.
I go through from [Here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603570/how-to-perform-nunit-testing-for-a-class-inherting-from-a-base-class-with-parame),  but did not clear my concepts.

I am attaching my part of code below.

**First part:**

```
public abstract class Streaming
{
    private static int _streamingIDExponent = 41;

    public const string MonthLookup = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
    public const string ExpiryStringFormat = "ddMMMyyyy";
    public const double DefaultTicksPerPoint = 3;
    private long _StreamingID;
    private int _minQty = DefaultMinimumQty;
    public virtual void SerializeBinary(BinaryStreamWriter binaryStreamWriter)
    {
        binaryStreamWriter.Write(_StreamingID);
        binaryStreamWriter.Write(_ex_StreamingID);
        binaryStreamWriter.Write(_minQty);
        binaryStreamWriter.Write(_extendedProperties.Count);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<StreamingPropertyName, StreamingProperty> dictionaryEntry in _extendedProperties)
        {
            dictionaryEntry.Value.SerializeBinary(binaryStreamWriter);
        }
    }

    public virtual bool DeserializeFromBinary(BinaryStreamReader binaryStreamReader, out string errorString)
    {
        errorString = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            _StreamingID = binaryStreamReader.ReadInt64();
            _exStreamingID = binaryStreamReader.ReadInt64();
            _minQty = binaryStreamReader.ReadInt32();    
        }
        catch (Exception oEx)
        {
            errorString = oEx.Message;
        }

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorString);
    }
```

**second Part:**

```
public class Asset : Streaming
{
    public override void SerializeBinary(BinaryStreamWriter binaryStreamWriter)
    {
        base.SerializeBinary(binaryStreamWriter);
    }

    public override bool DeserializeFromBinary(BinaryStreamReader binaryStreamReader, out string errorString)
    {
        if (!base.DeserializeFromBinary(binaryStreamReader, out errorString))
            return false;

        try
        {
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception oEx)
        {
            errorString = oEx.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Third Part:**

```
 public class BinaryStreamWriter : IDisposable
 {
    private BinaryWriter _binaryWriter;
    public BinaryStreamWriter(BinaryWriter binaryWriter)
    {
        _binaryWriter = binaryWriter;
    }

    public void Write(object value)
    {
        if (value is Boolean) Write((Boolean)value);
        else if (value is Byte) Write((Byte)value);
        else if (value is Byte?) Write((Byte?)value);
        else if (value is Byte[]) Write((Byte[])value);
        else throw new InvalidOperationException(value.GetType().ToString());
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
         (_binaryWriter as IDisposable).Dispose();
    }
 }
```

Kindly suggest me accordingly.

Comment: Question isn't clear. Where is the test you are asking about?

Comment: @Charlie  Here, I have **SerializeBinary()**  and **DeserializeFromBinary()** methods in first part. I have not written test class for testing it.but my aim is like below:
in first part **SerializeBinary()** method will give binary stream format of passed object and **DeserializeFromBinary()**  method will give previous same object which is converted into binary stream by **SerializeBinary()** method.
then I want to compare both for same type or not.
Here base class is **Streaming**. hope it is understandable now.

Comment: In my classes and coaching, I have always stressed that it's best to test Serialization and Deserialization separately. If you test them together, then it's possible that they will work together because they both have errrors, which cancel one another. Of course, if these are private methods, and the serialized result is not intended to be used by any other application, that's ok. But it's not usually the case.